# Textview ellipsis last sentence messed up on older devices

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout, ellipsis

There is an ellipize bug I cant seem to figure out.
[image]

As can be seen the `...` are in the middle of the sentence and there are some words missing on the left side. (the missing text: ut labore et dolore magna)

I think it's specific for older phones because this was tested on a Galaxy S2 (GT-I9105P Android: 4.2.2) and I have no problems on my Nexus 5 (Android: 6.0.1)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        ...
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="@string/lorem_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_holder"
        ....
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show us the @string/lorem_description? Be sure, that it does not contain '\n'.

Comment: You are onto something, I removed the newline from the input text and suddenly it did work. But the newline was after where the text should be cut. `Ut enim ad minim veniam,{newline}quis nostrud exercitation`